# How to make easy access to struct as matrix

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I want to create a `struct` which would be able to have a matrix and some parameters; so, for example, I have:

```
struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double** data;
} A;
```

I want to use, instead of `A.data[x][y]`, easy access like`A[x][y] = A.data[x][y]`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable though a bit tricky.

You could use technique similar to one used in [Simple Dynamic Strings](https://github.com/antirez/sds). Just place metadata before the actual matrix data.

Define your structure like this:

```
struct matrix {
  int rows, cols;
  double *data[];
};
```

Allocate it like a typical structure with flexible member.

```
malloc(sizeof(struct matrix) + rows * sizeof(double*))
```

Now the twist.

Rather than returning a pointer of `struct matrix` from `matrix_create()` return `matrix.data`, the *pointer to member*.

```
double **create_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
  struct matrix *m = malloc( ... );
  ... Allocation of rows
  return m->data;
}
```

This way you could use nice `A[i][j]` notation.

Next add a macro to translate this pointer to member back to `struct matrix` in a similar fashion as [container_of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof#Usage).
Exemplary implementation.

```
#define to_matrix(ptr) (struct matrix*)((char*)ptr - offsetof(struct matrix, data))
```

Now you can implement `matrix_get_rows()` like this:

```
int matrix_get_rows(double **A) {
   struct matrix *m = to_matrix(A);
   return m->rows;
}
```

You can implement similar helpers and destructor in the similar way.

A typical usage could be:

```
int main() {
  double **A = matrix_create(1,1);
  A[0][0] = 42;
  printf("%d %d\n", matrix_get_rows(A), matrix_get_cols(B));
  // should print "1 1"
  
  matrix_release(A);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i want to make not a A.data[x][y] , but a A[x][y] = A.data[x][y] for easy access. Any ideas?

The members of a struct are accessed through that struct only via the member selection operator (`.`).  They are accessed through a pointer to the struct only via the indirect member selection operator (`->`).  C does not have operator overloading, so the form `A[x][y]` is not an alternative.

You could create a function or macro to hide the involvement of the `data` member, but personally, I don't think that would be better or clearer.